# how to not get the integer array again

Tags: android, button

Im making question and answer. my question generate randomly but, the question repeated again.

im using txt file as my database when the int array generate randomly my holder get what is string line in my database. supposed to be int array = x, and string line = y;
     {y==x}. my question is when i generate again the question get again, what supposed i will do guys?.

```
             private void question() {


          InputStreamReader inputStream = new InputStreamReader
            (getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.question1));
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(inputStream);

            ArrayList<Integer> ar= new ArrayList<Integer>();
            int[] number= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
            for (int i : number) {
                ar.add(i);


            }

            Random r = new Random();


            int select = r.nextInt(ar.size());
            int random = ar.get(select);
               ar.remove(select);               
            String theLine="";
            int lineCtr = 0;

            try {          

            while ((theLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {

            if (lineCtr == select) {    

        StringTokenizer st = new   StringTokenizer(theLine,",");
            while(st.hasMoreTokens())

        {   

            //reading and getting data from the database","
                         String a = st.nextToken();
                         String b = st.nextToken();
                         String c = st.nextToken();
                         String d = st.nextToken();
                         String e = st.nextToken();
                         String f = st.nextToken();

                         //button setText
                         question.setText(a);
                         ca.setText(f);
                         firstbutton.setText(e);
                         secondbutton.setText(d);
                         thirdbutton.setText(b);
                         fourthbutton.setText(c);
                     //assigning
                         firstholder =e;
                 secondholder =d;
                 thirdholder=b;
                 fourthholder =c;
                break;

                     }

                  }lineCtr++;

            }  


            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 


}
```

Comment: stil not clear for me.please elaborate more

Comment: sir Narendra  thanks, my question is method. when i click the button submit to confirm if the answer is correct, if the answer is correct the question method will be call again to generate again a question. the problem is the int array that i removed will back again.. please help me sir. do you want to post my codes?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try below code for solve repeating question problem :-

```
Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(number));
```

Comment: where i will put collections?

Comment: it randomize again sir. can you help me to debug this?:(

Comment: then why question are repeating.

Comment: i did arraylist and int[] put to the top to enable it as a private or public.. i'`ve got question repeated. I dont know HCD im 3 weeks only in android.

Comment: i can't understand what u say what if problem is question repeating then you have to use shuffle function in your array int ......

Comment: my goal is to get 10 unique question randomly. the problem is duplicating question.

Comment: than simply use define ur integer array like this =======  int[] number= {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};  and after dat u have to use ======  Collections.shuffle(Arrays.asList(number)); now u dnt need to run random function......

Comment: is the number inside the shuffle is the data? how i will compare it to an integer?